# NServiceBus MessageDeserializationException on DataBusProperty<byte[]>

Tags: json.net, rabbitmq, nservicebus

We have an NServiceBus 6 environment with a number of services that send files between each other using DataBusProperty over a custom SqlDataBus : IDataBus.

This works fine on NSB6 using the built in JSON serializer, but is now broken after we moved to NSB7 and the NewtonsoftSerializer.

Removing DataBusProperty from our classes and just using byte[] works fine.  We also tried changing the DataBus to FileShareDataBus but got the same exception:

```
NServiceBus.MessageDeserializationException: An error occurred while attempting to extract logical messages from incoming physical message c7b5cd47-c1b7-4610-9f6c-aa7800cc9b64 --->
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading bytes. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'Data.Key', line 1, position 68.
```

This fails even if a service is sending messages to itself. Also we can see the files written to the file store, whether on Sql or File Share, so they're serializing fine.

An example payload from the error queue is

```
{"ExecutionId":"1db85105-a71c-4b29-87da-9b7ae6518c1c","Data":{"Key":"2019-06-26_13\\6a2b63c7-12b0-46dd-8b92-f1fc743d27c1","HasValue":true}}
```

How can we get this to deserialize in NSB7+NewtonsoftSerializer when it works fine in NSB6+JsonSerializer?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your message types?

Comment: Are you using data bus property as `byte[]` via naming convention or via `DataBusProperty<byte[]>` property type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just spent about 8 hours trying to figure out what was going on, and realized, that for whatever reason, NSB7 wants a paramaterless constructor and settable properties.  I am going back to Particular to see if this change is expected, but I expect we will have to adjust all of our message classes to fit that paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Although data bus properties should work there is also an alternative to data bus properties which is using stream attachments via send options:

- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/attachments-sql

Depending on the use case using `Streams` might be a more efficient approach.